# Trigger loadOptions in react-select/async once option has been click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have an async `react-select` component

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import Async from "react-select/async";

const MySelect = ({
  label,
  options,
  asyncSelect,
  loadOptions,
  components,
  placeholder,
  fixedHeight,
  onSelect,
  ...props
}) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const asyncRef = useRef();

  const [fieldValue, setFieldValue] = useState();

  // Gets called when an option is chosen or created.
  const onChange = value => {
    setFieldValue(value);
    if (onSelect) onSelect(value);
  };

  // Toggle menu by presence of input.
  // Reset value if input is emptied.
  const onInputChange = (value, context) => {
    if (!value && context.action === "input-change") {
      onChange(null);
    }
  };

  // Restore input value.
  const onFocus = () => {
    if (fieldValue) {
      asyncRef.current.state.inputValue = fieldValue.label;
      asyncRef.current.select.state.inputValue = fieldValue.label;
      asyncRef.current.handleInputChange(fieldValue.label);
    }
  };

  // Close menu when pressing enter. Submit does not work on mobile.
  const onKeyDown = event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      onMenuClose();
    }
  };

  // Blur select element to trigger onFocus on next click.
  const onMenuClose = () => {
    asyncRef.current.select.blur();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={ref} />
      <Async
        ref={asyncRef}
        {...props}
        value={fieldValue}
        components={components ? components : null}
        loadOptions={loadOptions ? loadOptions : () => null}
        placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : "Select..."}
        searchPromptText="Start Typing"
        autoload
        isSearchable
        searchable
        cacheOptions
        // Hook into events to make the editing work.
        onChange={onChange}
        onInputChange={onInputChange}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        onMenuClose={onMenuClose}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default MySelect;
```

I use this component in another component to load an array and filter options from the input value

```
const loadOptions = async inputValue => {
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(getOptions(inputValue)));
};

const getOptions = async inputValue => {
  // how to trigger this to be called within loadOptions when option is selected?
  if (asyncOptions && asyncOptions.length > 0) {
    const options = asyncOptions.filter(item =>
      item.label.toLowerCase().startsWith(inputValue.trim().toLowerCase())
    );
    if (options && options.length > 0) {
      return options;
    }
    return [];
  }
  await delayWithPromise(1000);
  return [];
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <MySelect
      name="addressLookup"
      className="addressLookupContainer"
      label="Address Lookup"
      asyncSelect
      components={{
        DropdownIndicator: () => null,
        IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
        NoOptionsMessage: val => <NoOptionsMsg>No Options</NoOptionsMsg>
      }}
      loadOptions={loadOptions}
      onSelect={val => console.log(`${val.value} selected`)}
    />
  </div>
);
```

However, I want it so when I select an option, it then loads another list (without the list closing, instead loads a new list in the old lists place), but I am unsure how I can retrigger the `loadOptions` prop within `react-select/async` when I click on an option?

An example would be an address search, where you search for a street/ post/zip code and there is an option stating how many address with that street, then selecting that option would then trigger `loadOptions` make an API call to find all address in that street, therefore, brining in a new list of options. Hopefully, that makes sense?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-leaf-gvo8u?file=/src/App.js:1144-2215) with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a go at the Codesandbox link you posted.
The `onSelect` prop can be used to detect if user has selected anything.

```
  const [firstValue, setFirstValue] = useState("");
  const [secondValue, setSecondValue] = useState("");

  const onSelect = option => {
    if (firstValue) setSecondValue(option?.value);
    else setFirstValue(option?.value);
  };
```

Now we know, if the `firstValue` is selected, we would need to toggle the options. So, by that logic -

```
    const getOptions = async inputValue => {
    const optionChunk = firstValue ? secondOptions : firstOptions;
    if (optionChunk && optionChunk.length > 0) {
      const options = optionChunk.filter(item =>
        item.label.toLowerCase().startsWith(inputValue.trim().toLowerCase())
      );
      if (options && options.length > 0) {
        return options;
      }
      return [];
    }
    await delayWithPromise(1000);
    return [];
  };
```

Check out the codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-fast-hwwf5?file=/src/App.js:1574-2017) for more details. I have tweaked a few variable names here and there, which made more sense to me.

**EDIT**

Re-opening the menu when the user selects the first value -

So, when we have `firstValue` and not the `secondValue`, we can pass a `prop`(let's say - `retainFocus`) -

```
<MySelect
   ... otherProps
   retainFocus={!!firstValue && !secondValue}
/>
```

In `MySelect`, we can add a `useEffect` on `retainFocus`, which would just re-focus the select box if passed as `true`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (retainFocus) {
      asyncRef.current.select.focus();
    }
  }, [retainFocus]);
```

Check the updated codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-antonelli-vim8w?file=/src/MySelect.js).

**EDIT**

I also added a method to go back to first list when user input is empty.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's not exactly what I was aiming for, I want to when you click on the first option, the list doesn't close, instead, it remains open and loads the new list. So a user doesn't have to click the input again if you get me?

Comment: Okay, got it. So, I gave it a try. I made use of a ```prop``` which would be sent to ```MySelect``` as ```true``` only when the user has entered the ```firstValue``` and not the ```secondValue```. Based on that, I am switching the focus again, which should reopen the menu. Check out the codepen [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-antonelli-vim8w?file=/src/MySelect.js). Let me know if it works. @mcclosa